# django rest framework perform_update or post_save return custom response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can i return custom response json error when object is older then 8 minutes.

Here is my code, but response doesn't work:

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    instance = serializer.save()
    diff_minutes = (datetime.now() - instance.ordered_date).total_seconds() / 60
    if diff_minutes > 8:
        return Response({'expired': True}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    self.post_save(instance)
```

Same this is when i use `post_save`.

I don't get any response, it always pass.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Because of the division, this code may return json error if instance expired 9 minutes ago, but not 8.

Comment: I tested on 20 minutes, problem is with return Response i think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you want to return a 500 error specifically then you can just raise an `APIException`.  For example:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException

def perform_update(self, serializer):
    instance = serializer.save()
    diff_minutes = (datetime.now() - instance.ordered_date).total_seconds() / 60
    if diff_minutes > 8:
        raise APIException("expired")
    self.post_save(instance)
```

Raising the `APIException` will trigger the `.handle_exception(self, exc)` function.  Which by default will return a result like:

`{detail : "expired" }`

and a status code of `500`.  If you need more control over the exact return value / status code you can overwrite the `handle_exception` function and get it to return whatever you like.

Also since apparently I don't have enough rep to comment, for you question to the previous posted solution stating that you only want to do the validation on update.  You can just overwrite the `update()` function in your serializer and that will only be called on update as opposed to `create()` which will be called when you create a new object.

Answer (score 7):

In the code of the `rest_framework`, `perfrom_update` is called this way:

```
class UpdateModelMixin(object):
    """
    Update a model instance.
    """
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If you want to modify what is responded, you can modify `serializer.data`, but you can't do anything for the status because **it is not the right place**.

To validate your data, you should add a validator like explained in the documentation http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

Comment: But i need this only when update, how can i do validator only on update?